# How can I add/insert to a subdocument array in CakePHP?

Tags: php, mongodb, cakephp, php-mongodb

Ok, so I have done alot of searches on this site and Google and found some answers, but none of it has worked. I also have checked out @ichikaway's site and test procedures. Even the thing in there don't work for me. Also, when wrapping the save/update with an 'if' statement it always returns true, so there isn't much debugging I can do.

Below is the relevant code that might help you in guiding me to a solution. Thanks!

MyClass Model definition

```
class MyClass extends AppModel 
{
var $name = 'MyClass';
var $useTable = 'my_classes';

//var $belongsTo = array();
//var $hasMany = array();

var $useDbConfig = 'mongo';

var $mongoSchema = array(
        '_id' => array('type' => 'integer', 'primary' => true, 'length' => 40),
        'children' => array(
                'child_id' => array('type' => 'integer','length' => 40),
                'child_first_name' => array('type'=>'string'),
                'child_last_name'=>array('type'=>'string'),
                'active'=>array('type' => 'integer', 'length' => 1),
        ),
        'teachers' => array(
                'teacher_id' => array('type' => 'integer','length' => 40),
                'teacher_first_name' => array('type'=>'string'),
                'teacher_last_name'=>array('type'=>'string'),
                'primary'=>array('type' => 'integer', 'length' => 1),
                'active'=>array('type' => 'integer', 'length' => 1),
        ),
        'name' => array('type'=>'string'),
        'active'=>array('type' => 'integer', 'length' => 1),
        'created'=>array('type'=>'datetime'),
        'modified'=>array('type'=>'datetime'),
        );
}
```

Code from my StudentsController

```
$currentClass = $this->data["MyClass"]["id"];

$classtoedit = $this->MyClass->findById($currentClass);

$addChildToClass = array(
    'MyClass' => array('id'=>$currentClass,
    '$push' => 
        array('children' => 
        array('child_id'=>$newChildId,
            'child_first_name'=>$first_name,
            'child_last_name'=>$last_name,
            'active'=> 1)
        )
      )
    );

print_r($addChildToClass);
$this->MyClass->id = $currentClass;
if($this->MyClass->save($addChildToClass))
{
$this->Session->setFlash("Your child has been successfully added.");

}
```

**EDIT:**
I was able to get the functionality I needed via only PHP terms, but again, really want to do it the right way in CakePHP. I'd rather not mix the two together for any other maintainers who might come after me. FYI

Comment: Should $currentClass = $this->data["MyClass"]["id"]; be referring to "_id" rather than "id"?  Same for $this->MyClass->id - plus you already have $classtoedit, no?

Comment: I would have thought so, but it for some reason doesn't. In the database it's _id but when it gets received in CakePHP it's just "id". That part seems to work fine though. It's just the subdoc stuff I can't get to work.

Comment: If I change it to `"_id"` in the data array, I get:  E11000 duplicate key error index: weebehavedev.my_classes.$_id_  dup key: { : ObjectId('51a051f9f1d0bab103000000') }

Comment: It's completely ignoring my second parameter in the array that starts with $push. Here's a SQL from the DebugKit showing it only picking up the `_id` parameter. `db.my_classes.insert( {"_id":ObjectId ("51a051f9f1d0bab103000000"),"modified":"MongoDate(0.52900000 1369630553)","created":"MongoDate(0.52900000 1369630553)"} , true)`

Comment: Also, why is it choosing to do an insert instead of update?

Comment: Do you have the most recent version? I used this Plugin several months ago and it didn't work too well for me. I used a newer version last week and it is much better.

Comment: yessir, it's all the most recent version as this is a new install.

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](https://github.com/ichikaway/cakephp-mongodb/wiki/How-to-use-MongoDB-update-operators), it looks like you also need to use `mongoNoSetOperator`.

There are examples of it's usage in the [tests](https://github.com/ichikaway/cakephp-mongodb/blob/master/tests/cases/datasources/mongodb_source.test.php#L742).

I also think that you need to use `_id` rather than `id`. In your use-case, you are trying to update an existing record so if the driver code calls `insert` rather than `update` you should be getting a duplicate key exception.

Comment: Unfortunately I had tried all of that too. I can't explain it, but I eventually just decided to do it only through PHP. Works like a charm, but don't get the ability to stay in the CakePHP framework.

Answer (score 0):

Two thing i want to highlight, please let me know if i am wrong.

1) Why you are setting id twice one in the array variable `$addChildToClass` and other `$this->MyClass->id = $currentClass;`

2) What is key ''$push'`in the`$addChildToClass`?

i think if you will try the array with something like this.. then it will work

```
$addChildToClass = array(
    array('children' => 
    array('child_id'=>$newChildId,
        'child_first_name'=>$first_name,
        'child_last_name'=>$last_name,
        'active'=> 1)
  )
);
```

Because any way you are setting the id before updating the field.

Comment: You are correct that the `$this->MyClass->id = $currentClass;` probably isn't needed, it was just a last chance desperation to set the current record I wanted to update. CakePHP uses that with a typical database so I figure, what the hell, give it a try. Couldn't hurt, as it did the same thing with or without.  As for the $push, that is definitely needed to add to a subdocument array without overwriting the current attributes and values.